# Magento 2 Data Migration Ignore Product Attributes & Attribute Sets

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

What's the best way to ignore product attribute sets and product attributes? Already have my migration script ignoring products and categories.

Answer (score 6):

At `magento-data mioration tool` there is folder under `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/(ce-to-ee/ce-to-ce/ee-to-ee)/`
a file :-

```
eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist
```

here inside of :-

```
 <group name="ignore">
....
</group>
```

add

```
<attribute type="[Attribute_Entity_type]">[Attribute_Code]</attribute>
```

**`[Attribute_Entity_type]`**   will be

- `catalog_product` for **product attribute**
- `catalog_category` for **category attribute**
- `customer` for customer **attribute**

Example: Suppose you want remove size attribute for migration

then add this:-

```
<group name="ignore">
  <attribute type="catalog_product">size</attribute>
</group>
```

Comment: Yeah but what if we want to ignore the entire catalog, categories etc.

Comment: Hi @amit bera can u help me on how to ignore attributesets?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/oow4y8 can u suggest me how to fix this

Comment: Hi @AmitBera How to ignore all categories tables ?