# Data MIgration failed

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, data-migration-tool

While Practicing on data migration in magento 1. I got this error, and i found that i have to ignore these attributes in eav attribute file. am i right?
But i don't know how to convert this into XML code to writable there. Can someone help my by giving me example of the one or below error showing.

```
>         
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:08][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:08][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:08][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:08][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
>     [2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>     [0;33m[2018-11-20 05:19:14][WARNING]: Source documents are not mapped: magegiant_dailydeal[0m
>     [0;33m[2018-11-20 05:19:14][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order. Fields: dailydeals[0m
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:14][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:14][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:14][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:14][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:14][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:14][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:14][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:14][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
>     [2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:18][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
>     [2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:20][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: started
>     [2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class megamenu/category_attribute_source_type_style does not exist but
> mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=134[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class megamenu/category_attribute_source_block_subcolumns does not exist but
> mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=136[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class megamenu/category_attribute_source_block_columns does not exist but
> mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=138[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class megamenu/category_attribute_source_block_columns does not exist but
> mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=140[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class megamenu/category_attribute_source_label_categorylabel does not exist
> but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=143[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class megamenu/category_attribute_source_type_float does not exist but
> mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=144[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class megamenu/category_attribute_source_block_yesno does not exist but
> mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=147[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class megamenu/category_attribute_source_block_yesno does not exist but
> mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=148[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=153[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=154[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=155[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=156[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=157[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=158[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=159[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=160[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=161[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=162[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=163[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=164[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=165[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode does not exist but mentioned
> in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=166[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/system_config_source_setting_product_page_type does not exist
> but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=167[0m
>     [0;31m[2018-11-20 05:19:21][ERROR]: Class porto/system_config_source_setting_product_image_size does not exist
> but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=168[0m
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:21][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: Error occurred. Rollback.
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:21][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: EAV Step: rollback
>     [2018-11-20 05:19:21][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: Please fix errors and run Migration Tool again
>     
>       [Migration\Exception]
>       Volume Check failed
>     
>     
>     migrate:data [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] [--] <config>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are choosing data-migration tool of magento.

Go to your magento2->vendor->magento->data migration tool.

Hope you done the config.xml setup.Inside config.xml change class-map.xml.dist to class-map.xml.

Then choose the class-map.xml.dist file change to class-map.xml file and remove the class which is not find in new.

example : `<rename<from>megamenu/category_attribute_source_type_style</from>
        <to></to>
       </rename>`

Comment: I changed the class-map.dist to class-map.xml already. and can you please specify the example you just wrote/ Because there are not only just classes in the error. There are blocks and types also. Is I also need to change the file name in config.xml file?

Comment: For blocks and types you can see the other map.dist files in your data migration tool-> version folder and change this dist file to xml file and add ignore tag to avoid the use of blocks and types. Hope this will help you to avoid those things.

Comment: Thanks N ameen its working

Answer (score 1):

***Your issue happens for some category attributes which are related to your Magento 1 Porto Theme.***

In magento1, you have some category attributes which using Proto theme some class as Source model. As  you ***don't have the same theme existing at my your magento2 theme and  Magento 1 and Magento 2 source model mapping different*** and Magento2 full page class source model as source model.

Example;

```
  'display_mode' => [
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'label' => 'Display Mode',
                        'input' => 'select',
                        'source' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode::class,
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 10,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'group' => 'Display Settings',
                    ]
```

See Magento2: Mapping `'source' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode::class`.

Where magento 1 is follow: `'source'                     => 'catalog/category_attribute_source_mode',`
like

**Solution:**

In this case, there are two solutions:

**1.** Ignore all attribute which is related with the proto theme  like at eav-attribute-groups.xml

```
<group name="ignore">
  <attribute type="catalog_category">[ATTRIBUTE_CODE]</attribute>
</group>
```

See how to ignore an attribute during data migration check out the article https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170907/4564

**2.** You have the convert the code of  `porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode`  class to magento 2 stucture.

Comment: What if i want to ignore the attribute by its id because there are too much errors of attribute showing by their id not by their attribute name. So how can i ignore them all?

Comment: I already ignored the attribute fields and documents error in their specific files, the only remaining error was of class, now I just simply mentioned the classes in the map class.xml in the <from> section and blank <to> section and user the -r -a in command that make is successfully run. Thank for your Help bro.